# Differentiable function question about pair of points

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f \ :\ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Is it true that for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists pair of points $a<x_0<b $ such that $f^\prime(x_0)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. How to check this?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^3$ and $x_0=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counter example: $f(x) = x^3$ and $x_0 = 0$. The derivative is zero but the difference quotient cannot be zero, since the function is strictly monotonic. In fact any strictly monotonic function with a zero derivative somewhere suffices as a counter example.

(By the way, is the numerator in that order ($f(a)-f(b)$) intentionally?)

Comment: Hey you stole that example from my comment.  :-)

Comment: First one that comes to mind :D

Comment: My mistake the numerator in the question should be $f(b)-f(a)$ does this change anything?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The numerator can't be zero, since those two numbers are never same (the function is injective).